# Does creating a custom graph data structure violate any principles?

Tags: c++, data-structures, theory

I'm working on a small scientific course project related to circuit testing using continuous methods. The program would parse circuit definition files and then build an easily modifiable graph structure representing the circuit.Then certain modifications are done to that graph, and it is topologically sorted. After sorting, the graph is converted into a static structure that consists of a list of arrays, where every array corresponds to a certain topological sorting degree. After that, the circuit can be simulated easily as you can rely on the sorting order and process the model sequentially.

Now that is all nice and logical, but the two graphs I mentioned are custom data structures, which:

1)Are not built quite to the STL specifications (would be long and difficult for me anyway - graphs are way more complex than vectors and lists)

2)For the second graph, I assume it's not modifiable and use a vector of vectors or a list of vectors for speed.

3)The set of operations available for my graphs is limited and reflects the needs of my project.

4)The code is simple.

Now I'm just a 3rd year IT student, and after having done a course in Software Design and after reading some real life code, I wonder:

*1)Can (or even may) the code be as simple?*

*2)Don't I violate any of the thousands of principles of Software Design with making assumptions about the data structures?*

*3)Should I really always conform to STL specifications for all the data structures I create in this and future projects?*

This project uses C++.

Thank you for your attention! I'd appreciate a fundamental and theoretical answer to these questions, as well as an example of practical approach to this problem.

Comment: Please, don't give this a homework tag. Be respectful Thank you.

Comment: How do you represent the first graph ? Adjacency lists or similar structures can be built with standard containers. Did you also look at boost::graph data structures ?

Comment: IIRC it's like a list of vertices and a list of edges, and edges know what vertices they connect. So you can insert/remove data fast. And yes, I know about Boost, but as this is a university project, my aim is ti demonstrate I can code, not to use the already available solutions. There'd be little code of mine should I choose to use Boost::Graph and other libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)Can (or even may) the code be as simple?**

Not only can it be, it should be. There is no need for code to be complicated.

**2)Don't I violate any of the thousands of principles of Software Design with making assumptions about the data structures?**

Um, how can you do otherwise. This question doesn't make sense to me.

**3)Should I really always conform to STL specifications for all the data structures I create in this and future projects?**

Nope. For example, if you don't need to iterate a structure, don't provide iterators. Only implement what you actually need.

Comment: Well my bad, in point 2) I was mainly referring to the idea that code should be more generic and less custom, or something like that, what we were taught at school.

Comment: @Semen Designing truly generic code is very, very difficult. Even the C++ Standard library took years to get to its current (still less than ideal) state. You should design your code to correctly and clearly meet your current requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I would see nothing wrong with a simple design like this:

```
typedef int node_type; // or a more complex type here
typedef std::list<node_type> node_list;
typedef std::pair<node_list::const_iterator, node_list::const_iterator> edge_type;
typedef std::list<edge_type> edge_list;

struct graph
{
    node_list nodes;
    edge_list edges;

    // Some member functions for doing specific things here
    // for instance:
    void remove_node(node_list::iterator i)
    {
        nodes.erase(i);
        edges.remove_if(connects(i));
    }
};
```

where

```
struct connects
{
    connects(node_list::const_iterator i) : i(i) {}

    bool operator()(const edge_type& e) const
    {
        return e.first == i || e.second == i;
    }

private:
    node_list::const_iterator i;
};
```

It stays simple, modular, and allows you to use the standard library on it. It allows you to iterate on nodes and edges. If you want the adjacency list of a vertex, you will have to loop over the whole edge list, but this is by design (you want a better structure if you want to do this fast).

For instance, define (this one is unfortunately not standard)

```
template <typename I, typename F, typename G>
F for_each_if(I first, I last, F f, G pred)
{
    for ( ; first!=last; ++first ) if (pred(*first)) f(*first);
    return f;
}
```

and now you can do

```
for_each_if(g.edges.begin(), g.edges.end(), something, connects(some_node));
```

to iterate over the adjacency list of `some_node`.

With C++0x there are more elegant ways to code such algorithms (using lambdas).

Comment: While this design seems to be not as fast, it demonstrates a different approach to the subject. I guess I need to study more C++0x and STL. I'm not yet used to coding in functional style.

Comment: @Semen: Indeed, such an approach enables you to leverage the STL algorithm for your application. However, you will soon realize that STL algorithms really suck without lambda functions. If you have access to a C++0x compiler, then feel free to use this approach. Otherwise, this may prove too cumbersome for a simple project.

Comment: That is ingenious! Switching to C++0x could be a solid bonus for my work, although I don't have the time to learn this new tech. BTW, it's not yet standartized, may I ask you to point me to a decent language/STL implementation? Will G++ 4.x branch work?